# Golang компиляция со статической линковкой

Tags: golang, компиляция, линковка

ОС: `Windows 10 x64-86`; 
Пытаюсь скомпилировать файл со включенной статической линковкой.
**main.go:**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, world")
}
```

Компилирую вот так:

```
set CGO_ENABLED=0 & go build -ldflags "-w -s -extldflags '-static'" main.go
```

**Результата 0**, тот же самые вес исполняемого файла что если бы со CGO_ENABLED=1 я скомпилировал бы вот так:

```
go build -a -ldflags "-w -s" main.go
```

Размер выходного файла - более 1мб, примерно 1,024mb

Что в данном случае делать / или от этого размера никак не избавиться ибо как я знаю у Golang есть свой `Common Language Runtime`.

Comment: А что именно не нравится? про какой размер речь?

Comment: @vnn198 обновил, размер хелоуворда - 1мб, хотелось бы в пределах сотни кб как это в Си

Answer (score 0):

Из-за встроенного CLR это нормальный размер, можно дополнительно уменьшить размер собрав его с флагом *GOARCH=386*